# ERROR 403 Forbidden. This action is unauthorized

Tags: laravel-backpack

I installed https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Demo

The CRUD seems to work for all the models apart from the User, Roles and permissions.

Any time i try to edit or add a new user, role or permission I get taken to a "ERROR 403 Forbidden. This action is unauthorized." page.

I did a bit of searching through the code and have found the authorize method is whats causing it. For example in PermissionCrudRequest the method \Auth::check(); returns false. I'm not sure why this is exactly.

Laravel 5.6.39
Using PHP 7.2.1
MySql 5.7.23

Any idea why I'm getting this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I needed to set the default guard to 'backpack' in the /config/auth.php file

Comment: The issue has been resolved in the source code of the demo. See issue: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Demo/issues/71

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution @Edin!